# Auto deployment from Maven to Tomcat 8 using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have setup Jenkins for auto-deploy to Tomcat 8 from Maven, but I'm getting this error:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "package". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/mywebapp/pom.xml to com.tastyminerals.poems/poemcollection/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/poemcollection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

Tomcat 8, Maven 3.3.9, Java 1.8, as per the configuration I have done below settings

Tomcat:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

For Maven Authentication in this path `%MAVEN_PATH%/conf/settings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings ...>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>TomcatServer</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

---

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/mywebapp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "packege".
```

It is clear from the above message, you mentioned wrong maven target name.

Instead of "packege" use "package". Spelling mistake is there.

But "package" target only creates the jar/war/ear files only it wont deploy to tomcat server.

Use [tomcat7:deploy](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) target to deploy the artifact into tomcat server.